# Scrolling static content when view is smaller than content

Tags: html, css

This probably is a lot simpler than I am making it, but I am having a hard time figuring this out.

I have a webpage displaying a list of contacts on the left, with a static preview of the selected contact information on the right.  The menu on top is also static.  Currently, it is 'almost' working correctly.  The left list of contacts scrolls when I scroll with the mouse scroll button or the screen scrollbar, while the contact preview and menu stay static.  However, I would like the right section to scroll only when the screen is too small to show the entire contents of the preview.  I have used 'overflow: auto' and 'overflow: scroll' without success.

```
.scrollable {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Could any of you help me solve this issue?

Here is the jsfiddle (please note that not all CSS and code is included - but I think the functionality required for this question is included.

http://jsfiddle.net/84BM8/7/

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/84BM8/8/

Comment: No - I definitely want it to be static on the top menu and right side - I just want the side bar to be able to be scrolled whenever the content is too small (still kept in the same place though).  I don't want to use iframes, but it'd be similar to the same concept.  Another similar example would be the old way Outlook Webmail was done.

Comment: Essentially, requirements are:  scrollable left side based on normal screen scrolling, static right side 'unless' the screen is too small, in which case it will be scrollable within the right section - not scrolling with the screen as a whole.  Menu stays static as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to hide the overflow of `html` and `body`.

Then you need to specify a height so that the right content will overflow when there's not enough space.

```
.rightSection {
    width: 45%;
    float: right;
    height:500px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/84BM8/13/embedded/result/)

Comment: I actually wouldn't want to hide the overflow of the body, since I still want it to scroll for the long list - but the height is exactly what I was missing.  I probably will use the viewport size to determine what height I need to use for the particular screen.  I figured it was something simple!  Thanks :)